# What is the best way to create an online indexed library of images, video and documents?

Tags: web-applications, web, streaming, cloud

I have a client who is a charity-funded conservation group with hundreds of hours of video, thousands of images and documents and would like them all to be available to the public from their website via some kind of library/search system. It will also need the tools for uploading all of this data too and tagging/organising it with meta-data for searching.

As it's a charity-funded group money is limited but not miserly so something open-source would be ideal but a reasonably priced commercial package would be fine as well.

I haven't been able to find anything that does everything I need so I'm asking you good people for your expert advice.

Is there a package available for this kind of thing already or should I make one myself? I can work in C# or PHP and the client already has a standard shared hosting apache server for their website.

Thanks for your time

Comment: I've not used it personally, but you might want to read about Google's offerings to help sites provide search facilities: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630969?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-[Apache Nutch Participates in Google Summer of Code](http://nutch.apache.org/) as Google may have inspired ASF to create the Nutch (open source - knowledge data mining or K.D.M) toolset which includes  indexing / clustering tools. [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) integrates well to [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), and [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) clusters can scale to petabyte / exabyte and beyond (nill vendor license fees) providing highly scalable distributed processing & analytic 'nodes'.

Multiple services, protocols and languages make Nutch. [PIG](http://pig.apache.org/) provides a language 'Pig Latin', to create custom Map-Reduce apps, run over distributed nodes. [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) provides a means of (de-)normalising NoSQL for OLAP data warehousing & get data back into a familiar world of SQL & relational database schemas and tools from the [Many big data vendors.](http://www.capgemini.com/sites/default/files/technology-blog/files/2012/09/big-data-vendors.jpg).

[Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) has ELK (ElasticSearch, LogStash, Kibana) and is worth looking into.

Going full Big-Data may be overkill. [Lucene.Net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/) provides C# bindings, ported from Java and is a quick way to run with Lucene as an inverted index. It powers search for Autodesk and the BBC UK Top Gear site and at an early stage in development was maintained by Dawid Weiss and Stanislaw Osinski, who were unable to dedicate the time and resources required to maintain such a massive project, alongside their own open source framework Carrot2.

[Carrot2](http://project.carrot2.org/) is search clustering framework & has a commercial side in the [Lingo3G clustering algorithm](http://carrotsearch.com/lingo3g).

I've been working with [Node.JS](http://nodejs.org/) lately and looking at [Forage.JS](http://www.foragejs.net/), a JavaScript implementation, light and installed by NPM. This is quick and minimal, support for [stemming algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and [Mozilla's localForge](http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/) provides a minimal offline storage engine, easily adapted to PHP based sites.

[Twitter's TypeHead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) provides suggestions based on an index and is similar to Google Suggest, inspired by JavaScript indexing.. [Backbone Typeahead](http://mojotech.github.io/backbone.typeahead/) is a Node NPM module forked from Twitter.

Index calculations, ordering crawled content to binary trees, can be done many ways. It depends on what you prefer really as there are so many tools available and so many projects to play with, [Inorder-Tree-Layout](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/inorder-tree-layout) another NPM package.. classification of content from MIME type for example...

Jon Abernathy provides a PHP port of Martin Porter's "[Porter Stemming Algorithm](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/)", based on Snowball and [phpMorphy](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/) can be used to produce 'real words' from an index and I found a [PHP Magneto SOlr plugin](https://github.com/sebastianmaurer/Magento-Solr), which maybe useful in someway on GitHub.

I'd probably start with Elastic Search and Lucene, grab the desktop app and start having a play about to get the idea for what exactly you want to achieve, take it from there & have a lot of fun! :-)

Comment: That's a lot of information, thanks! If no-one finds a pre-made package I can use I'll mark this as the answer and get reading.